# Auto generate count days after user submits date

Tags: javascript, html

I tried using onclick on a button to count the days of between 2 dates, and generate it in a *textbox* and it works. However, im not sure how can I make when a user entered a date on *"input type date"*, and it auto counts and generate the number of days in *textbox*. Any ideas how ?

My HTML

```
            <td><b>Start Leave Date:</b></td>
            <td> <input type="date" name="leave_start_date" id="leave_start_date" required></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><b>End Leave Date:</b></td>
            <td> <input type="date" name="leave_end_date" id="leave_end_date" required onclick="noOfDays"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td> <b>No of Days:</b> </td> <td> <input type="text" name="noOfDays" id="noOfDays" readonly>Days <button type="button" name="button" onclick="countdays()">Count</button></td>
            </tr> 


<script type="text/javascript">
function countdays () {
  var dateend = new Date (document.getElementById("leave_end_date").value);
  var datestart = new Date (document.getElementById("leave_start_date").value);
  var counttime = dateend.getTime() - datestart.getTime();
  var countdays = counttime / (1000 * 3600 * 24);
  document.getElementById("noOfDays").setAttribute("value",countdays);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `onchange="countdays()"` to each of the date `input` elements:

```js
function countdays () {
  var dateend = new Date (document.getElementById("leave_end_date").value);
  var datestart = new Date (document.getElementById("leave_start_date").value);
  var counttime = dateend.getTime() - datestart.getTime();
  var countdays = counttime / (1000 * 3600 * 24);
  document.getElementById("noOfDays").setAttribute("value", isNaN(countdays) ? '' : countdays);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Start Leave Date:</b></td>
    <td><input type="date" name="leave_start_date" id="leave_start_date" onchange="countdays()" required></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>End Leave Date:</b></td>
    <td><input type="date" name="leave_end_date" id="leave_end_date" onchange="countdays()" required onclick="noOfDays"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>No of Days:</b> </td> 
    <td><input type="text" name="noOfDays" id="noOfDays" readonly>Days <button type="button" name="button" onclick="countdays()">Count</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @AfiqHussaini glad to help!  if this answer completely solved your issue, please consider marking it as accepted.

Comment: done! sorry that im new here. not familiar with the surroundings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use listeners to detect when a user has finished entering a date & try to auto-calculate it!

See: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6ae5L4g0/)

```html
<td><b>Start Leave Date:</b></td>
            <td> <input type="date" name="leave_start_date" id="leave_start_date" required></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><b>End Leave Date:</b></td>
            <td> <input type="date" name="leave_end_date" id="leave_end_date" required onclick="noOfDays"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td> <b>No of Days:</b> </td> <td> <input type="text" name="noOfDays" id="noOfDays" readonly>Days <button type="button" name="button" onclick="countdays()">Count</button></td>
            </tr> 


<script type="text/javascript">
  var txtdateend = document.getElementById("leave_end_date");
  var txtdatestart = document.getElementById("leave_start_date");
  
  txtdateend.addEventListener("change", countdays);
  txtdatestart.addEventListener("change", countdays);
  
function countdays () {
  var dateend = new Date (document.getElementById("leave_end_date").value);
  var datestart = new Date (document.getElementById("leave_start_date").value);
  var counttime = dateend.getTime() - datestart.getTime();
  var countdays = counttime / (1000 * 3600 * 24);
  document.getElementById("noOfDays").setAttribute("value",countdays);
}
</script>
```

The new section being:

```
  var txtdateend = document.getElementById("leave_end_date");
  var txtdatestart = document.getElementById("leave_start_date");

  txtdateend.addEventListener("change", countdays);
  txtdatestart.addEventListener("change", countdays);
```

You can look into `listeners` here: [onchange Event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp)